# String replacement with linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have this query it is suppose to get the ip addresses and match them to the  DeviceUIDs which is located on another table. I am looking to replace the "." in the IP Address with "0" but the way I have the code running right now it does not replace the "."

Can anyone help me with this please.

```
 var etjoin = (from e in dxlXs.AsEnumerable()
              join t in tstarresults on new String(e.Field<String>("Ip Address").Replace(".","0").ToArray()) equals t.DeviceUID
              into leftjointable
              from x in leftjointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new ATTModel
              {
                  ATTIP = e != null ? e.Field<String>("IP Address") : "N/A",
                  ATTICCID = e != null ? e.Field<String>("ICCID") : "N/A",
                  ATTSTATUS = e != null ? e.Field<String>("SIM Status") : "N/A",
                  ATTSession = e != null ? e.Field<String>("In Session") : "N/A",
                  ATTActivated = e != null ? e.Field<String>("Activated") : "N/A",
                  IP = x != null ? x.DeviceUID : "N/A",
                  VehicleName = x != null ? x.VehicleName : "N/A",
                  VehicleGroupName = x != null ? x.VehicleGroupName : "N/A",
                  PhoneNumber = x != null ? x.UserDefinedColumn2 : "N/A"
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Well your replace is in the *join* - where were you trying to perform the replacement? Can you show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? (Just a couple of properties would be fine...)

Comment: As Jon says you are doing the replacement in the join - if you want it in the ATTModel then you'll need to do the replace there as well.

Comment: yes I have it in a join because the dxlXs is in a excel sheet and tstarresults are in a sql table.

example I want 123.34.45.67 to convert into 123034045067 to find the DeviceUID 123034045067 in the SQL table

Comment: Since your string in the join must be equal to `t.DeviceUID`, why not just select the `t.DeviceUID` instead of `e.Field<string>("IP Address")` in your `ATTModel` initializer?

Answer (score 1):

First [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a new string with replaced characters, so you don't need the constructor `new String(char[])` ([ctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Second there is nothing explicit wrong with the string replacement.
e.g. `"127.0.0.1".Replace(".","0")` returns `"127000001"`
So you have to be more precise on what is "wrong".

Third your logic is a left join so if you're expecting `null` values for `e` when creating your `ATTModel` you have to check for null in `e.Field<String>("Ip Address")` too. (one can guess `dxlXs` is a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thus the rows are not likely being `null`)

Answer (score 0):

With your replace in the `Join`, you are creating a new string just for the purposes of making the join. That string is assigned or stored anywhere, so `e.Field<String>("Ip Address")` will still have the same value (with the dots).

If you need `ATTIP` to have the value with the `.` replaced with `0` (although I'm not sure that really makes sense), then you could do something like:

```
 var etjoin = (from e in dxlXs.AsEnumerable()
              let temp = e != null ? e.Field<String>("Ip Address").Replace(".","0") : "N/A"
              join t in tstarresults on temp equals t.DeviceUID
              into leftjointable
              from x in leftjointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new ATTModel
              {
                  ATTIP = temp,
                  //...
              }).ToList();
```